# PHP: register_long_arrays deprecated (HTTP_*_VARS)

Tags: php, deprecated

I recently updated to PHP 5.3.6 and there were some deprecated functions and INI directives. I have the following function:

```
function ServerVar($varName) {
global $HTTP_SERVER_VARS;
global $HTTP_ENV_VARS;

if(!isset($_SERVER))
{
    $_SERVER = $HTTP_SERVER_VARS;
    if(!isset($_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"]))
        $_SERVER = $HTTP_ENV_VARS; // must be Apache
    }

if(isset($_SERVER[$varName]))
    return $_SERVER[$varName];
else
    return "";
}
```

Running that function caused an error in apache log:

```
<b>Deprecated</b>:  Directive 'register_long_arrays' is deprecated in PHP 5.3 and greater in <b>Unknown</b> on line <b>0</b><br />
```

I modfied the code like this:

```
if(!isset($_SERVER))
{
    $_SERVER = &$HTTP_SERVER_VARS;
    if(!isset($_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"]))
        $_SERVER = &$HTTP_ENV_VARS; // must be Apache
    }

if(isset($_SERVER[$varName]))
    return $_SERVER[$varName];
else
    return "";
}
```

however the the same error still appears in apache log. What is the best way to resolve this problem?

Thank you!!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In PHP 5.3 (<s>really, I think any version of PHP 5 or later</s> [any version of PHP newer than 4.1.0](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php)) you shouldn't ever need to use `$HTTP_SERVER_VARS` or `$HTTP_ENV_VARS`. Just use `$_SERVER`. If that does not work, then your server needs to have it's configuration fixed; not code workarounds like this induced.

Comment: Sorry. The code was implemented 4 years ago. I am just doing some maintenance on it :( And it's painful since the code was following FO instead of OO :(

Comment: @Tanner: No reason to be sorry. :) Hope there are fewer WTFs in your future :)

Comment: `$_SERVER` has actually existed since PHP 4.1.0, which was released nearly ten years ago (December 2001). Anything that ancient has much bigger problems. :)

Comment: Cool! That solves the problem. Sorry :P I am not a PHP coder :D